# How to write app.yaml for vast php project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I have a ready php website. For that website I am writing `app.yaml` for google app engine.
I read so many answers but it doesnt help me.
I am facing problem with php files under various subfolders in `libraries` folder.
In `index.php`, i accept `rss feed url` and process it for full text feed by calling other php files. but getting this error.

```
/makefulltextfeed.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fnews.google.co.in%2Fnews%3Fpz%max
=10&links=preserve&exc=&submit=Create+Feed was not found on this server.
```

How to write `app.yaml` for all php files which comes under various sub-folders??
Do i have to write `handlers:` for all individual php files??
I am stuck here for whole day.
I am new to this topic. So if you find this as stupid question please forgive me.
Here is my app.yaml

```
application: xxxx-xxxx-90212
version: alpha-001
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /config
  script: config.php

- url: /makefulltextfeed
  script: makefulltextfeed.php

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: css



- url: /images
  static_dir: images
```

I have php files in subfolder. How to write app.yaml for that.

Comment: Hey Roon.... this is honestly super unclear. Mind showing some code from your handler, and your app.yaml? anything to get us going really....

Comment: @Patrice i updated my question..is it enough?

Comment: Apparently it was, look at aqquadro's answer ;)

Comment: @Patrice Thank u. You made this question perfect for guys like me..beginners.

Comment: that's the point of stack :) so that other people can look at your question and get the same answer ^^. Happy to have helped. Enjoy the Cloud!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_About_app_yaml) you can use this notation to match all root path, that ends with .php, to a php script

```
# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

This config assume that each your URL ends with .php, you can modify url regex to catch all urls (I test only the regex but I think it's works :) )

```
# Serve ALL php scripts.
- url: /((.+\/).*)$
  script: \1.php
```

Or you can simulate httpd mod_rewrite as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/mod_rewrite).

Comment: You are real genius man. Its working for me. The concept of app.yaml is quite confusing..